# How can I quickly add new fields to var declarations in VSC?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, loopback4

This is my first question here, so apologies for any mistakes.

I'm currently doing migration of several TS-based webservices from LB 2 to 4 and I've found myself rewriting a LOT of the same code due to how Loopback v4 changed it's model definition syntax.

Say I have the following old code...

```
const foo = ds.define('foo', {
  string1 : String,
  num1 : Number,
  string2 : String,
  string3 : String,
  num2 : Number,
  string4: String,
  string5: String
}
```

And I must rewrite it this way...

```
@model()
export class foo extends Model {

  @property({ type: 'string', required: true })
  string1 = '';
    
  @property({ type: 'number', required: true })
  num1 = 0;

  @property({ type: 'string', required: true })
  string2 = '';

  @property({ type: 'string', required: true })
  string3 = '';

  @property({ type: 'number', required: true })
  num2 = 0;

  @property({ type: 'string', required: true })
  string4 = '';

  @property({ type: 'string', required: true })
  string5 = '';
}
```

I have to do this several dozens of times and it feels like there must be a tool out there to simplify this process!

*So basically, adding a @property marker with the proper type...*

```
@property({type: 'string', required: true})
```

*To the beginning of each var declaration*, also ending it with assignment of value. (Although, as far as I'm aware, defining it's type as-is in the old code works too.)

**What tools/extensions in Visual Studio Code could assist me in quickly reformatting these model definitions? I'm aware of multi-cursor and search-replace, but i'll appreciate any directions towards faster ways of doing this.**

I mostly tried multi-line selections and find-replacing - which works way better than manually fixing these fields. My searches on the Internet have mostly led me to methods I've already used - I'm likely not able to explain the concept of what I need clearly enough to the search engine - or well, what I'm looking for might very well not exist.

Comment: write an extension that transforms the selected text

Comment: ts-morph can definitely help with this, and would not be hard to get started with.

Comment: @CollinD This looks like a good starting point! I'll look into it - thank you Collin!

Answer (score -1):

An idea is to use an extension to modify the selected text.  Using [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform) (an extension that I wrote) make the following keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",                           // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "description": "migrate TS webservices from LB 2 to LB 4",
  "args": {

    "replace": [
      "$${",
        "const selectedText = document.getText(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection);",
        "const lines = selectedText.split(/\\r?\\n/);",  // to handle different OS's

        "let newStr = '@model()\\n';",
        "let regex = /(?<=define\\(')(.*)'/;",
        "newStr += `export class ${lines[0].match(regex)[1]} extends Model{\\n`;",

        "lines.pop();",                   // remove last element of array: }
        "lines.shift();",                 // remove first element of array: const foo = ds.define('foo', {

        "regex = /\\s*([^\\s:]*)\\s*:\\s*([^,]*),?/;",
        "const indent = '\\t\\t\\t\\t';",  // however many tabs or spaces you want 

        "lines.map(line => {",

          "const parsed = line.match(regex);",

          "if (parsed[2] === 'String') {",
            "newStr += `${indent}@property({type: 'string', required: true})\\n`;",
            "newStr += `${indent}${parsed[1]} = '';\\n`;",
          "}",
          "else if (parsed[2] === 'Number') {",
            "newStr += `${indent}@property({type: 'number', required: true})\\n`;",
            "newStr += `${indent}${parsed[1]} = 0;\\n`;",
          "}",
        "});",

        "newStr += `}`;",
        "return newStr",
      "}$$"
    ]
  }
}
```

The extension allows you to write javascript and use it in a `replace`.  It gets your selected text (via the vscode api), breaks it into lines and then creates an output string depending on the regex it runs on each line.  If you have other types it should be easy to modify the code to handle them as well.

[image: demo of variable transform using Find and Transform extension]